# Waterline ORM equivalent of insert on duplicate key update

Tags: sql, node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

I have a table user_address and it has some fields like

```
attributes: {
  user_id: 'integer',
  address: 'string' //etc.
}
```

currently I'm doing this to insert a new record, but if one exists for this user, update it:

```
UserAddress
  .query(
    'INSERT INTO user_address (user_id, address) VALUES (?, ?) ' +
      'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE address=VALUES(address);',
    params,
    function(err) {
       //error handling logic if err exists
    }
```

Is there any way to use the Waterline ORM instead of straight SQL queries to achieve the same thing? I don't want to do two queries because it's inefficient and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a custom model method that does what you want using Waterline queries isntead of raw SQL. You will be doing two queries, but with Waterline syntax.

Example below (if you don't know about deferred objects then just use callback syntax, but the logic is the same):

```
var Q = require('q');

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    user_id: 'integer',
    address: 'string',
    updateOrCreate: function (user_id, address) {
      var deferred = Q.defer();

      UserAddress.findOne().where({user_id: user_id}).then(function (ua) {
        if (ua) {
          // UserAddress exists. Update.
          ua.address = address;
          ua.save(function (err) {deferred.resolve();});
        } else {
          // UserAddress does not exist. Create.
          UserAddress.create({user_id: user_id, address: address}).done(function (e, ua) {deferred.resolve();});
        }
      }).fail(function (err) {deferred.reject()});

    return deferred.promise;
  }
};
```

Comment: Waterline already returns bluebird promises by default. Why would you add Q into the mix? There's a much more elegant way to do this with the promises that are already native to waterline.

Comment: @WulfSolter The question is about "update or create".

Comment: Well, that may be the title but the user did say: "I'm doing this to insert a new record, but if one exists for this user, update it" and the OP's code example reflects this. `findOrCreate` is incapable of updating the record if exists and `.updateOrCreate()` doesn't exist yet, check [#790](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/790).

Comment: @Dário & crzrcn Apologies! Too many late nights - I was just about to refactor some upsert functionality in my SailsJS codebase and got them confused. Can't wait for [PR 940] (https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/pull/940) to get in to 0.11

Answer (score 7):

The answer above is less than ideal. It also has the method as part of the attributes for the model, which is not correct behavior.

Here is what the ideal native solution looks like that returns a promise just like any other waterline model function would:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    user_id: 'integer',
    address: 'string'
  },
  updateOrCreate: function (user_id, address) {
    return UserAddress.findOne().where({user_id: user_id}).then(function (ua) {
      if (ua) {
        return UserAddress.update({user_id: user_id}, {address: address});
      } else {
        // UserAddress does not exist. Create.
        return UserAddress.create({user_id: user_id, address: address});
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then you can just use it like:

```
UserAddress.updateOrCreate(id, address).then(function(ua) {
   // ... success logic here
}).catch(function(e) {
   // ... error handling here
});
```

Answer (score 4):

@Eugene's answer is good but it will always run 2 operations: `findOne` + `update` or `create`. I believe we can optimize it further because if the record exists we just need to run `update`. Example:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    user_id: 'integer',
    address: 'string'
  },
  updateOrCreate: function (user_id, address) {
    return UserAddress.update({user_id: user_id}, {address: address})
    .then(function(ua){
      if(ua.length === 0){
        // No records updated, UserAddress does not exist. Create.
        return UserAddress.create({user_id: user_id, address: address});
      }
    });
  }
}
```

BTW, there is an open request to implement `.updateOrCreate` in waterline: [#790](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/790)